# Wrong widget order using vbox layout PyQt

Tags: python, widget, pyqt

I am trying to put a QLabel widget on top of (ie before) a QLineEdit widget edit.

But it keeps appearing after the QLineEdit widget. My code,

```
class CentralWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CentralWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        # set layouts
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        # Flags
        self.randFlag = False        
        self.sphereFlag = False
        self.waterFlag = False

        # Poly names
        self.pNames = QtGui.QLabel("Import file name", self) # label concerned
        self.polyNameInput = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)           # line edit concerned

        # Polytype selection
        self.polyTypeName = QtGui.QLabel("Particle type", self)
        polyType = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        polyType.addItem("")
        polyType.addItem("Random polyhedra")
        polyType.addItem("Spheres")
        polyType.addItem("Waterman polyhedra")
        polyType.activated[str].connect(self.onActivated)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.pNames)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.polyNameInput)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pNames)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.polyTypeName)
        self.layout.addWidget(polyType)
        self.layout.addStretch()

    def onActivated(self, text):
        # Do loads of clever stuff that I'm not at liberty to share with you

class Polyhedra(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        super(Polyhedra, self).__init__()

        self.central_widget = CentralWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        # Set up window        
        self.setGeometry(500, 500, 300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Pyticle')
        self.show()

    # Combo box
    def onActivated(self, text):

        self.central_widget.onActivated(text)

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    poly = Polyhedra()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The window I get is below.

What am I missing? I thought QVbox allowed to stack things vertically in the order that you add the items to the main widget. (Are these sub-widget objects called widgets?)

[image: The window I get,]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you are adding `self.pNames` label to layout twice.

```
#portion of your code
... 
self.layout.addWidget(self.pNames)        # here 
self.layout.addWidget(self.polyNameInput)
self.layout.addWidget(self.pNames)         # and here
self.layout.addWidget(self.polyTypeName)
self.layout.addWidget(polyType)
self.layout.addStretch()
...
```

The first time you add the `QLabel`, it gets added before the `LineEdit` and when you add it second time, it just moves to the bottom of `LineEdit`. This happens because there is only one object of `QLabel` which is `self.pNames`. It can be added to only one location. If you want to use two labels, consider creating two separate objects of `QLabel`

Comment: Spent the best part of an afternoon trying to workout what was going on. Sometimes you need that second pair of eyes to point out the obvious... Thanks